# Systemd[1] : Freezing Execution --Error

Tags: startup, systemd

Help me out here: I can't boot into my OS.
 I am currently using Ubuntu 16.04LTS and i turned on my laptop, they asked me to fix `fsck` manually, i fixed it using `fsck -a /dev/sda1` and it fixed itself, now its showing me this.

[image]

Systemd[1] freezing execution -- startup error

Comment: How old is your HDD?  Are you able to boot up livecd and do check the number of disk errors from gnome-disks?

Comment: it is fairly new.

Answer (score 1):

Your HDD has gone bad. I have faced the same error sometime back on Ubuntu 14.04.  I had to get my HDD replaced. You can try connecting the HDD to different computer and try to recover important data. In my case I lost all data :(